# ServiceAddress is empty when using Consul Registrator

Tags: service, infrastructure, consul, devops

```
[
  {
    "Node": "consul-staging-a-1.org",
    "Address": "10.0.11.221",
    "ServiceID": "mesos-slave-staging-a-1.org:determined_bartik:5000",
    "ServiceName": "service1",
    "ServiceTags": null,
    "ServiceAddress": "",
    "ServicePort": 4003
  },
  {
    "Node": "consul-staging-a-1.org",
    "Address": "10.0.11.221",
    "ServiceID": "mesos-slave-staging-a-1.org:angry_hypatia:5000",
    "ServiceName": "service1",
    "ServiceTags": null,
    "ServiceAddress": "",
    "ServicePort": 4007
  }
]
```

This is what I get from querying the Consul service API (/v1/catalog/service/service1).

Commands that I used to start registrator and services:

```
docker run -d  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock -h $HOSTNAME gliderlabs/registrator consul://consul-staging-a-1.org:8500

docker run -d -p 4003:5000 -e "SERVICE_NAME=service1" docker-training/hello-world
docker run -d -p 4007:5000 -e "SERVICE_NAME=service1" docker-training/hello-world
```

Any steps I'm doing wrong? How do you assign the hostname to ServiceAddress field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issue and found that before v6 Consul Registrator leaves ServiceAddress empty, but in v6 (at the moment the latest) it is "0.0.0.0". I've tried to use "-ip" option but it did not help, somehow it assigns internal IP address of the container. Found related issues at:

- https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator/issues/240

In my case I fixed it by binding container to IP address like:

```
docker run -d -p 10.0.0.3:4003:5000 -e "SERVICE_NAME=service1" docker-training/hello-world
```